# Using Javascript to check form elements and enabling/disabling the search button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I need your help,

Using javascript, how could I add some sort of data form validation that would be two-fold:

1st Event, [OnKeyUp] attached to all of the input boxes

2nd Event, [OnChange] attached to all of the select boxes

**Typical User Scenarios**

If there is any data present in any of the input boxes and no selected option values then { enable the search button } else { keep the search button disabled }

If there are any selected option values who’s option value is not null and no data present in all of then { enable the search button } else { keep the search button disabled }

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<form id="myform">
Cars
 <select id="car">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Fruits
 <select id="fruits">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="banana">banana</option>
  <option value="pear">pear</option>
  <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
  <option value="mango">mango</option>
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Vegetable
<input type="input" id="veggie">
<br><br>
Number
<input type="input" id="number">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="search" id="search" disabled>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var car=$('#car'); var fruits=$('#fruits');
var veggie=$('#veggie'); var number = $('#number');
$('select').change(function(){
    validate();
});
$('input').keyup(function(){
    validate();
});
function validate(){  
   if(($(veggie).val()!='' || $(number).val()!='') &&
       $(car).val()=='' && $(fruits).val()==''){
           $('#search').prop('disabled',false);
   }else if($(veggie).val()=='' && $(number).val()=='' &&
          ($(car).val()!='' || $(fruits).val()!='')){
           $('#search').prop('disabled',false);
   }else{
     $('#search').prop('disabled',true);
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="myform">
Cars
 <select id="car">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Fruits
 <select id="fruits">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="banana">banana</option>
  <option value="pear">pear</option>
  <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
  <option value="mango">mango</option>
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Vegetable
<input type="input" id="veggie">
<br><br>
Number
<input type="input" id="number">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="search" id="search" disabled>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work to criteria, a value was selected in the dropdown box and some text was typed in an input box and vise-versa. The result was a still a disabled search button.

Comment: that's your requirement number 1 isn't it?  Text in any input + no option select = enable button else disabled

Comment: Yeah, that's what I assumed in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you want to enable the button if only one of the `select` elements has a value *or* one of the `input` elements has a value, but not if both (or neither) do.

If that's the case then this should work, and it allows you you add as many elements to it as you need by adding IDs to the arrays at the top.

https://jsfiddle.net/j7by6bsz/

```
var selectInputIds = ['fruits', 'car'];
var textInputIds = ['veggie', 'number'];

function setButtonState() {
    var hasVal = function(arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(document.getElementById(arr[i]).value) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  };
    var hasSelectValue = function () {
        return hasVal(selectInputIds);
    }
  var hasTextValue = function () {
    return hasVal(textInputIds);
  }
    var theButton = document.getElementById('search');
  var s = hasSelectValue();
  var t = hasTextValue();
    theButton.disabled = ((s && t) || (!t && !s)); // you can do this bit smarter, but this is explicit
}

(function attachStuff (arr, evt) {
  function listenIn(arr, evt) {

   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(arr[i]).addEventListener(evt, setButtonState);
   }
  }
  listenIn(selectInputIds, 'change');
  listenIn(textInputIds, 'keyup');

}())
```

Your requirements could use some clarification around what happens if both input types have values though.

Comment: Your code doesn't work to criteria, a value was selected in the dropdown box and some text was typed in an input box. The end result was a still a disabled search button.

Comment: Your requirements are vague. You state that if one has a value and the other doesn't, that enables the button. That's what this code does. You never indicate what happens when both have values, so myself and the other answerer had to guess. So our code does work to what you initially stated.